# Apply only to tr with certain parent

Tags: html, css, html-table, parent

I'm looking for a good way to apply styling only to certain tr elements. My original forums include global tr so I need to exclude it. not:(:first-child) is NOT an option for me. So I created a div called "globaldata" and I want to apply theming to tr only under that div. How can I do that?

Comment: trying to set that `tr` class

Comment: If `globaldata` is a class then `.globaldata tr {}` if it is an ID then `#globaldata tr {}` It helps if you post the  code you got so far

Comment: @Huangism: you are right,it will be helpful if he posts his html

Answer (score 3):

**assumed HTML**

[*if you are using globaldata as id* ]

```
 <div id="globaldata">
      <table>
      <tr><td></td> </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
```

.
    **CSS**

```
#globaldata tr {
  //style here
}
```

**OR**

[*if you are using globaldata as class* ]

```
<div class="globaldata">
      <table>
      <tr><td></td> </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
```

.
    **CSS**

```
 .globaldata tr {
      //style here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Set a class for the div, and do this:

```
<div class="globaldata">
  <tr> </tr>
</div>

.globaldata tr {
  color : blue
}
```